# Function runs before the tab has loaded - Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I am trying to find something on a new tab that I open from my chrome extension. The extension can open the tab but the Function runs before the script. I want a script or this function to run once the tab has loaded. 
This is my manifest.json file:

```
{
"name": "SwagBot",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "The Offical SwagBot extension to cop your supreme!",
"browser_action":{
 "default_popup":"popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
"https://*/*",
"http://*/*",
"storage",
"tabs",
"activeTab",
"webRequest",
"webRequestBlocking",
"webNavigation",
"declarativeContent"
]

}
```

Here is my javascript:

```
    function findItem(){
    allText = document.getElementsByClassName("name-link");
    console.log('start');
    for(i = 0; i < allText.length; i++){
      if(i % 2 == 0){
        names.push(allText[i].innerHTML);
      }else{
        colors.push(allText[i].innerHTML);
        links.push(allText[i].href);
      }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
      if(names[i].indexOf(itemName) != -1){
        name_flag = true;
        console.log('here');
      }
      if(colors[i].indexOf(itemColor) != -1 && name_flag == true){
        itemlink = links[i];
        console.log(itemlink);

    }
  }
}

  StartButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    chrome.storage.sync.get(["category",], function(items) {
      index_url = "http://www.TEHWEBPAGEIWANT.com" + items.category;
      console.log(index_url);
      chrome.tabs.create({
        url: index_url
      });
    });
    chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(findItem);
  });
  });
```

Any help would really be appreciated, thank you. :)

Comment: is this code is a part of popup.html? If so it will be executed in its context

Comment: You will need to inject a content script in the tab.